# Issue with installing new SSL certificate in my server

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, certificate

I am running an application in a Centos 6.4 VM. Last year I have installed SSL certificates from rapidssl vendor and everything was working fine till now. IT send me the new certificates and I installed them in a similar way but they do not work as expected.

The application I am running is a Django project which is using an Nginx server (and Uwsgi) together with Tomcat (tomcat6). In the Tomcat server there is a Geoserver deployed.

So after installing the new SSLs certificates the interaction of the application with the Geoserver broke. That means that certain functionalities (such as loading services from Geoserver etc.) do not work anymore.

Apparently the vendor of the new certificate is different (Comodo). They use 2 intermediate certificates, which can affect installs.

I also read that if the application hasn't been updated yet to allow industry standard SSL Certificate security then this could be the issue. But since I am not an administrator expert (neither SSL expert), I am not sure exactly what this means. I am trying to find out the source of the issue.

- Could it be the version of the OS (Centos 6.4?)
- Could it be the version of the python libraries (requests, urllib etc.?)
- Could it be the type of certificate we have?

Any hints how to tackle this issue would be highly appreciated.